# C# pointer arithmetic on byte array allocated from a struct

Tags: c#

From:

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84519/mastering-structs-in-c/

It is proposed to declare an array of bytes in a struct as a single byte and then allocate memory for the array using FieldOffset. Once the memory has been allocated, the array can be access using pointer arithmetic.

Example:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1, Size = 1300)]
public struct TGLProtocolBuffer
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte StartByte;
    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte MessageNumber;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public UInt16 Command;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public UInt32 UnitID;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public UInt16 DataLength;
    [FieldOffset(10)]
    public byte Data;
};
```

I would like to operate on this memory using Array.Copy but need to cast the array defined in the struct as a byte to byte[]

How can I cast a byte to byte[]?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a byte array within the struct, going over the whole thing. (this is the same as C++ unions)
Using this, you can access every single byte within the struct.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1, Size = 1300)]
public struct TGLProtocolBuffer
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte[] byteArray;   // <--
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte StartByte;
    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte MessageNumber;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public UInt16 Command;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public UInt32 UnitID;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public UInt16 DataLength;
    [FieldOffset(10)]
    public byte Data;
};
```

If you need this only for the the `Data` field, you can simple declare it as `byte[]` instead of `byte`.
OR you can use both:

```
    [FieldOffset(10)]
    public byte Data;
    [FieldOffset(10)]
    public byte[] DataArray;
```

You may need to define the array size with

```
public byte[1290] DataArray;
```

or

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst=1290)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not 'cast' a byte to a byte[], you can make a byte[] with one byte:

```
byte b = ...
byte[] ba = new byte[1];
ba[0] = b;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I am immediately aware of is to use a fixed byte in an unsafe context. This will end up creating a pointer to a `byte*`. Which is a little weird to use.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1, Size = 1300)]
unsafe public struct TGLProtocolBuffer
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte StartByte;
    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte MessageNumber;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public UInt16 Command;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public UInt32 UnitID;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public UInt16 DataLength;
    [FieldOffset(10)]
    public fixed byte Data[1290];
};
```

To get the actual byte array out of the data you will need a helper method.

```
unsafe static void GetBytesFromPointer(byte* data, byte[] output)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; i++)
    {
        output[i] = data[i];
    }
}
```

Then you should just need to call that like this.

```
var data = new byte[1290];
GetBytesFromPointer(tglProtocolBuffer.Data, data);
```

As an addendum to this here is a quick little way to test the marshaling.

```
unsafe public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var data = new byte[1300];
    new Random().NextBytes(data);
    fixed(byte* dataFixed = data)
    {
        dataFixed[10] = 0; //add marker byte so we can spot that extracted data starts with a 0 byte
        var tglProtocolBuffer = (TGLProtocolBuffer) Marshal.PtrToStructure((IntPtr) dataFixed, typeof (TGLProtocolBuffer));
        var bytesFromStruct = new byte[1290];
        GetBytesFromPointer(tglProtocolBuffer.Data, bytesFromStruct);
        Debug.Assert(bytesFromStruct[0] == 0);
    }
}
```